# How to pick the correct c# overloaded extension method called from a generic method

Tags: c#, generics, methods

I am struggling to get the correct extension methods called in generic methods.

I guess it is a limitation of compile time method picking but is there a clever way around this in C#?

```
[TestClass]
public class WrongOverloadSelection 
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void WorksNew()
    {
        new Generic<A>().Test();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void FailsGeneric()
    {
        PicksWrongOverload<A>();
    }

    public void PicksWrongOverload<T>()
    {
        new Generic<T>().Test();
    }
}

public class A{}
public class Generic<T>{}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Test(this Generic<A> source) { }

    public static void Test<T>(this Generic<T> source) 
    {
        throw new Exception("Not this one!");
    }
}
```

Comment: In some circumstances adding type constraints would be an option

Comment: It wouldn't sadly, and I just tried it to see and even PicksWrongOverload<T>() where T:A fails, I think I may have to do some MethodInfo reflection which is a shame because I wanted to provide the Generic implementation in a different class to the 'overloads'

Comment: You might be able to cast to `dynamic`: `((dynamic)new Generic<T>()).Test();` A better solution would be to add an overload of `PicksWrongOverload` which constructs a `Generic<A>`.

Comment: @Lee If I remember well, `dynamic` doesn't support extension methods

Comment: The problem is that calls inside `PicksWrongOverload<T>` are evaluated at compile time and that method code is generated. `T` doesn't inherits from `Generic<A>`, so the compiler must choose the other `overload`

Comment: I think that what suggested @Lee is basically correct, you just need to invoke the method with the traditional syntax and not as an extension method `Extensions.Test(((dynamic)new Generic<T>()));`

Comment: You should be re-designing your objects so that you're not using extension methods when you want them to behave as if they're instance methods.  You should be using instance methods if you want them to behave like instance methods.

Comment: I was waiting for the inevitable redesign it comment! Well if I explained to you the situation you would understand but lets just say a redesign is not possible. I'll try the dynamic hack but it still leaves me unable to use 2 extension classes (one core and one user implemented) because damn it Static extension classes cannot be partial!! But its better than nothing, thanks Lee and Matteo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Now it picks then right one
public static void PicksWrongOverload<T>()
{
    Extensions.Test((dynamic)new Generic<T>());
}
```

The reason for this is explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx), but essentially at runtime the CLR will convert the dynamic type to the required type of the routine, and if there is nothing happening that violates the type checking rules then you are good to go.